# Combining 2 coloumns into 1

Tags: sql-server

Find the customer number, last name, and first name.  Display the name as one column titled "Name"

```
SELECT A.CustomerNumber (A.LName B.FName) AS Name
FROM Customers as A
LEFT JOIN Customers as B
ON A.CustomerNumber=B.CustomerNumber;
```

What can I use to do this properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't it be as simple as this?

I cannot see any value in your attempt to join a row with the same row of the same table...

```
SELECT CustomerNumber
      ,LName + ' ' +  FName AS Name
FROM Customers;
```

Attention: Make sure, that both name parts are not `NULL`, otherwise the whole concatenated string will be `NULL`...

Comment: Yep lol thanks alot im new to sql didn't know wabout the + ' ' +

Comment: This fails if either LName of FName is NULL. By using the CONCAT-function, you avoid that.

Comment: both FName and LName are not null when i created the database so i shouldn't have that problem.

Comment: @BendikAugustNesbø, yes, but you'd need SQL Server 2012 or higher. And - as in this case - in all dbs I know the LName and FName columns were 'NOT NULL'. I try to avoid costly functions if not needed...

Comment: @Shnugo: No information was given that the FName and LName columns were defined as `NOT NULL`. In addition, since the OP was using a `LEFT JOIN `, B could easily contain nulls.

Comment: @BendikAugustNesbø, I see what you mean... That's why I included the hint about the NULL values. For me it was clear, that the attempts to join were not the expression of a high sophisticated database design, but rather of a lack of SQL experience :-) Anyway: Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [CONCAT-function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx), like this:

```
SELECT A.CustomerNumber, CONCAT(A.LName, ' ', B.FName) AS Name
FROM Customers as A
LEFT JOIN Customers as B
ON A.CustomerNumber=B.CustomerNumber;
```

Comment: That might very well be. However, I included it to be as similar to the original query that OP posted.